# How can I sort rows based on two columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has a bunch of rows, but only three columns, `date`, `username` and `posts`.

`Username` has usernames, and they repeat a lot. `Posts` has a bunch of numbers. `Date` has the date something was posted in the `Y-m-D` format.

Now when I run `SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = '2014-02-20'`, I get a bunch of mixed results, like this:

```
date                       username                    posts
2014-02-20                 user1                       1
2014-02-20                 user2                       2
2014-02-20                 user14                      1
2014-02-20                 user3                       1
2014-02-20                 user2                       3
2014-02-20                 user2                       4
2014-02-20                 user11                      1
2014-02-20                 user1                       2
2014-02-20                 user8                       2
2014-02-20                 user9                       3
2014-02-20                 user55                      4
2014-02-20                 user5                       3
```

I want to sort it out so it will look like this:

```
date                       username                    posts
2014-02-20                 user1                       1
2014-02-20                 user1                       2
2014-02-20                 user1                       3
2014-02-20                 user1                       4
2014-02-20                 user2                       1
2014-02-20                 user2                       2
2014-02-20                 user2                       3
2014-02-20                 user2                       4
2014-02-20                 user2                       5
2014-02-20                 user2                       6
2014-02-20                 user3                       1
2014-02-20                 user3                       2
```

How can I do that?

Comment: There's just a problem with both answers. `user10` comes right after `user1`, `user2` comes after `user19`, and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = '2014-02-20' ORDER BY username,posts ASC
```

Comment: I'll assign you the best answer because you answered in just 25 seconds, thanks.

Comment: I think user55 will come before user6 in this case

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM tablw WHERE date ='$something' ORDER BY username ASC, posts ASC
```

Comment: I think user55 will come before user6 in this case

Comment: @PrasanthBendra correct, I did that and `user10` came right after `user1`.

Comment: And before user2 rite ?

Comment: Yes, but that happened with both cases, `ORDER BY username,posts ASC` and `ORDER BY username ASC, posts ASC`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT *,CONVERT(SUBSTRING(username, 5, 9),UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS userord FROM table WHERE date = '2014-02-20' ORDER BY userord ASC, posts ASC
```